# Distillery Transfer Hoses

Tags: safety, alcohols, distillation

I was hoping an actual person could offer me some advice. I work in a craft distillery and I'm getting a lot of mixed information on how compatible PVC is with high-proof alcohol. It definitely seems that "Food-Grade" doesn't necessarily mean "Alcohol-Grade". 
A. Is PVC hose safe to use for transferring Grain, Water, and most importantly, Ethanol?
B. If not, is there a type of material you would recommend for any and all distillery applications?

Comment: Glass pipes may be best, but it's not like you'd die from vodka transferred using PVC hose. Unless you used it too much ;)

Comment: Subjectively, I don't think PVC is that bad, unless the hose is transferring boiling hot beverages or is constantly under sunlight. If you want a bullet-proof solution that can withstand solvents, oils and majority of other chemicals, maybe have a look at [cross-linked polyethylene (XLPE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-linked_polyethylene).